# Invalid Bracketing of name error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting an "Invalid Bracketing of name" error for the following code. I'm sure it has to do with what is inside the "[]", but what I'm trying to do is join a table on the ID from both tables and compare it to the stored ID (@ID).

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems WHERE ([Table2.ID = BlogEntryItem.ID] = @ID)"
```

This is what it looked like before I tried to do the join:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)"
```

I'm sure there is someone out there who can help.

Comment: You can't use `(x=y)=z` you need `(x=y) AND (x=z)`, and your `INNER JOIN` needs it's predicate in an `ON` clause, which you don't have.

Comment: I just tried this:

    SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON Table2.ID = BlogEntryItem.BlogID WHERE(Table2.ID = BlogEntryItem.BlogID AND Table2.ID = @ID)

And it still gave me a syntax error on the join operation.

Answer (score 6):

Your query needs to look like this

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    [Table2] INNER JOIN 
        BlogEntryItems ON  [Table2].ID = BlogEntryItem.ID
WHERE   [Table2].ID = @ID
```

You were missing the JOIN condition.

Comment: This is what I ended up trying (I needed to make a little change from my original post): 

    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON Table2.ID = BlogEntryItem.BlogID WHERE([Table2.ID] = @ID)">

I kept the WHERE ([Table2.ID] = @ID) syntax because that's what it looked like when it originally worked. It gives me a "Syntax error in JOIN operation.

Comment: I guess the one thing I should mention is that I'm doing this in an aspx page.

Comment: @Joseph: The `[Table2.ID]` part in your query is wrong. Try `[Table2].ID` like in astander's answer or omit the brackets completely *(they are only required when the table name contains special characters like blanks)*.

Comment: Tried it with no brackets whatsoever and it still didn't work. Why did the original working query (the one without the join in my original post) use brackets around ID?

Answer (score 2):

Your INNER JOIN needs the ON keyword rather than the WHERE keyword.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Table2 INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON Table2.ID = BlogEntryItem.ID"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
SelectCommand = "
  SELECT * 
  FROM Table2 
  INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON Table2.ID=BlogEntryItem.ID 
  WHERE Table2.ID = @ID"
```

Comment: This is what I ended up trying (I needed to make a little change from my original post):

    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2] INNER JOIN BlogEntryItems ON Table2.ID = BlogEntryItem.BlogID WHERE([Table2.ID] = @ID)">

I kept the WHERE ([Table2.ID] = @ID) syntax because that's what it looked like when it originally worked.